# How to get correct if-statement with similar words?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have re-edit my question and here I am..

My problem here following:

```
getInfo = 'filtered'
redisURL = ['unfilteredKeywords', 'filteredKeywords', 'orangeSElinks', 'orangePLlinks']

for getRedis in redisURL:
    if getRedis in getInfo.lower():
        print(getRedis)

outprint:

unfilteredKeywords
filteredKeywords
```

and here is the problem. What I am trying to achieve here is that I want to be able to only print out in this case `filteredKeywords` and not the `unfilteredKeywords`.

What I expect for outprint is that it should only print out

```
filteredKeywords
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case, it looks like it's good enough to catch all the cases that *start with* `getInfo`:

```
for getRedis in redisURL:
    if getRedis.lower().startswith(getInfo.lower()):
        print(getRedis)
```

If this isn't representative of all cases you'll be dealing with, then basic string functions may not be sufficient for the problem. Depending on what other values `getInfo` may take, and what other values it would need to be distinguished from, you may eventually need to play with the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module. It's a difficult problem to generalize though.

Comment: Hmm right, I mean it make sense of what you say. however the problem is that the `getRedis.decode("utf-8").lower()` seems to not find if we use ur if statement due to I believe `redisURL = redis.redis.keys('*Keywords')` where the actual `getRedis.decode("utf-8").lower()` would be `filteredKeywords` so I believe using ur if statement it wont find it due to it is missing the part of `Keywords`

Comment: etc for `for getRedis in redisURL: print(getRedis.decode("utf-8").lower())` would return `unfilteredkeywords, filteredkeywords`

Comment: Right but there goes the problem I believe, It seems like the word `filtered` would match `if getInfo.lower() in getRedis.decode("utf-8").lower():` if `getRedis.decode("utf-8").lower()` is unfiltered - and there is my problem, where it matches the word filtered inside a word that is unfiltered.

Comment: Exactly, I might have explained it bad but you get it now. but yes, etc if the word filtered is given, it should not be matching the word unfiltered and vice versa.

Comment: for this scenario it would be filtered and unfiltered. But in the future I might have a some that would called orangeSE, orangePL, orangeBR etc etc.

Comment: Alright will do that after dinner then, I was expecting I was abit out of the water but I will try to fix that right away :)

Comment: I've removed my previous comments as they're not relevant to the edited question.

Comment: Oh that was actually smart way to do. Once again I overcomplicated but that seems to be alot much fair to do!